# How can I know which app is using resources(mic, GPS) on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-sensors, android-security

I am interested in writing an app to record how the resources on my phone are used by those installed apps. These resources can be **microphone**, camera, bluetooth, **GPS**, contacts, network, battery usage, sensors etc. I would like to record when and how long did a app used a resource.

Is there any API on android which I can use to access those information ?

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.ihope will help you

```
 PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
                List<PackageInfo> applist = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
                Iterator<PackageInfo> it = applist.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
                    if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, pk.packageName)) //checking if the package is having INTERNET permission
                    {
                        results.add("" + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
                    }
                }
```

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774

http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html

also check these links :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Vanilla Boy, It looks like this code is checking which installed app is having the permission of the internet. Is there a way that I can record when does an app is using the internet or other recources?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor
-----------------------
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774
------------------------
http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.htmlCheck these links brother.it may help you :)